# What is a dynamic dust threshold system?

Tags: dust

According to the Wolfram Warptangent, [Point Release 1 notes](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/releases/tag/v0.10.1), Monero has `switched to a dynamic dust threshold system`

What does that mean? How is the definition of dust or its treatment dynamic?

Answer (score 2):

Dust threshold used to be considered as a fixed amount. The threshold is now dynamic in relation to the transaction fee.